# Given a finite set of sorted real numbers produce all possible subsets whose sum <= k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I would like to know if there exist algorithms that solves this issue. It is little bit similar to knapsack 0-1 problem, or power set problem however it is different.

Given a finite set of sorted real numbers we need to generate all possible subsets whose sum <= k. Here k is real, the sorted real numbers are all positive. For example an array = {1.48, 2.21 3.07, 4.35, 4.46} and k = 5.94 Output is : {4.46}, {4.46, 1.48}, {4.35}, {4.35, 1.48}, {3.07}, {3.07, 2.21}, {2.21}, {2,21, 1.48} and {1.48} .

One way to solve is to simply traverse from highest number {4.46} to see how many you can inlude in the basket then continue going next lowest number {4.35} and so on. Is there an efficient way to do this? let me know

Comment: Is the input really real numbers?or is it floating point numbers? or fixed point? is `pi` or `sqrt(2)` legal elements?

Comment: Also related: for integers, finding a subset that sums *exactly* to `k` is the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-Hard.

Comment: yes, lets assume that is fixed point...imagine that we take the pi or sqrt(2) and we can truncate it to 4 decimal places. yes, if we assume that it is integers, finding subset that sums exactly to k is the subset-sum problem which be solved with dynamic programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greedy algorithm can definitely work. To take advantage of the fact that the input is sorted, binary search can be used.

The basic idea is: first search for the biggest number in the array that is smaller than K by binary search, push the result element to a stack, then recursively search the subarray that ends at that element for a sum K - the value of that element. After this is done, search in the subarray for a sum K to cover the situations in which that element is not chosen.

Sample code:

```
void boundedSumSubarray(float * arr, int size, float K, stack S) {
    int pos=binarySearch(arr,size,K);
    if (pos>=0) {
        pushStack(S,arr[pos]);
        boundedSumSubarray(arr,pos-1,K-arr[pos],S);
        popStack(S);
        boundedSumSubarray(arr,pos-1,K,S);
    } else
        printStack(S);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "generate" all the subsets, not "count" all the subsets. That makes the job much easier :)

Let F(x,y,k) be the set of subsets of x[1:k] whose sum is less than y.

```
F(x,y,k+1) = F(x,y,k) \union { for each set g in F(x,y-x[k+1], k): g \union {k+1} }
```

Use the above recursion to generate all such cases.

Note that you don't have to actually recalculate the set of subsets when you do `F(x,y-x[k+1], k)`. Just keep the list in a tree structure.

If the number of subsets you are expecting is m, then this algorithm is O(nm).