# Subsequence having sum at most 'k'

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a **non decreasing** array **A** of size **n** and an integer **k**, how to find a subsequence **S** of the array **A** with **maximum** possible sum of its elements, such that this sum is at most **k**. If there are multiple such subsequences, we are interested in finding only one.

For example, let the array be {1, 2, 2, 4} so, n = 4 and let k = 7. Then, the answer should be {1, 2, 4}.

Brute force approach takes approximately O(n(2^n-1)) but is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Are all the elements positive ?

Comment: A possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844487/given-a-finite-set-of-sorted-real-numbers-produce-all-possible-subsets-whose-sum

Comment: @Damien yes, the elements are greater than zero.

Comment: The Wiipedia link provided by @Saibot gives an example of a simple dynamic programming algorithm. In a first step, you could try to implement it and check if it is fast enough

Answer (score 1):

In the general case the answer is no.

Just deciding if there is a solution where elements sum up to `k` is equivalent to the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and thus already NP-complete.

> The Subset Sum Problem can be equivalently formulated as: given the integers or
>   natural numbers `w_1,... ,w_n` does any subset of them sum to precisely `W`

However, if either `n` or the number of bits `P` that it takes to represent the largest number `w` is small there might be more efficient solution (e.g., a pseudo-polynomial solution based on dynamic programming if P is small). Additionally, if all your numbers w are positive then it might also be possible to find a better solution.

Comment: Thanks and yes, if all the numbers are greater than zero then what can be the possible dynamic programming solution?

Comment: @S13 k Without knowing the details: On the above Wiki page it is mentioned that Pisinger found an `O(N*C)` algorithm (where C is the upper bound of the weights) to check if a combination of weights exists that sums up to k. Checking all numbers from k to 0 with this method would give you `O(N*C*k)`.